# Find the image online based on location?

Tags: gps, search

I felt asleep with my daughter at certain point in Verona. When I woke up, some lady told me that many ppl took a photo of us.

I wonder what would be the most pragmatical way to search the net and check if some of those photos, taken at that location, are online? Just would like to have them, thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be quite difficult. The photographer would need to:

1. Upload the photo to a public site (Website, flickr, instagram, etc...). If they just post it to their Facebook, you may need to be friends with them (or tehir friends) to find/see it.
2. have geolocation (which phones have, but many cameras still do not) or manually tag the image with the location.

You could search on sites like instagram.com and flickr.com. (Find out if there's other photo sharing sites popular to that region)

You can also do an Image Search on Google for the location. You can filter results by clicking "Search Tools" and "Time" to show only those posted with in a certain timeframe.

Good luck.